# Distinguishing between files and directories in Python

Tags: python, file, directory

I am trying to  get only files in the folder excluding any other directories. but the below script is moving all the files and folders to another directory.

```
while True:
    # Go through each of the directories
    for mylist in dirlist:
        check_dir = mylist[0]
        callback = mylist[1]

        # get the list of files in the directory
        filelist = os.listdir(check_dir)
        for this_file in filelist:
            if ((this_file == ".") or (this_file == "..") or (this_file == "donecsvfiles") or (this_file == "doneringofiles")):
                print "Skipping self and parent"
                continue

            full_filename = "%s/%s"%(check_dir, this_file)
```

Comment: Do you also want the files in subdirectories, if any, included in the list?

Comment: no , just the files

Answer (score 7):

In *os.path*, there are helpful [*isdir()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) and [*isfile()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) functions:

```
>>> import os
>>> 
>>> os.path.isfile('demo.py')
True
>>> os.path.isdir('demo.py')
False
>>> os.path.isfile('__pycache__')
False
>>> os.path.isdir('__pycache__')
```

Also, you can use [*os.walk()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) or [*os.scandir()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) to automatically separate the two:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
    print('Searching:', root)
    print('All directories', dirs)
    print('All files:', files)
    print('----------------------')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `isfile` from `os.path` to check whether a path is a file or not. this code gives you a list of files in a folder:

```
from os.path import isfile, join
from os import listdir

folder = 'path//to//folder'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(folder) if isfile(join(folder, f))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.5+ offers a generator, which is often more efficient versus list comprehensions and loops. You can either traverse via `for i in arr`, iterate via `next(arr)`, or get a full list via `list(arr)`.

```
import os

arr = os.scandir('H:\public\python')  # returns a generator
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken almost directly from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) :

```
import os

with os.scandir('.') as it:
    for entry in it:
        if entry.is_file():
            print(entry)
```